# Why do I keep getting "No activity found to handle Intent" using PhoneGap and the barcode scanner plug-in?

Tags: android, cordova, barcode

I've built a simple app using PhoneGap and I'm trying to open the barcode scanner using the following code:

```
var scanCode = function() {
    window.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
        function(result) {
        alert("Scanned Code: " + result.text 
                + ". Format: " + result.format
                + ". Cancelled: " + result.cancelled);
    }, function(error) {
        alert("Scan failed: " + error);
    });
}
```

When I call this function I get an error:

```
Scan failed: No Activity found to handle Intent {act=com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner.SCAN cat=[android.category.DEFAULT]}
```

I also noticed the following error in the logs:

```
11-10 21:32:50.830: I/Database(1052): sqlite returned: error code = 14, msg = cannot open file at source line 25467
```

I've been stuck on this issue for hours. Can anyone offer advice?  By the way, I'm using a phone to test and not the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using at least PhoneGap 1.1.0 and did you update AndroidManifest.xml and res/xml/plugins.xml exactly as described at https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/BarcodeScanner.

There are additional step-by-step instructions [here](http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/home/start/twominutetutorials/tmt3).

Comment: Yes. That is exactly the instructions I followed with no luck.  I must have missed a step or did something wrong.

Comment: I wrote the mentioned tutorial, so very interested to know if and how your problem is fixed. Pls verify you are using AppLaud 1.2.5 and used instructions and barcode scanner from Nov 2 or later. I've introduced various errors to my project and library project, but can't generate your exact error.

Answer (score 0):

I can replicate this error by incorrectly nesting the `<activity> [barcode plug-in stuff] </activity>` inside of the main `<activity> </activity>` tags of the app in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Answer (score 0):

The linked site says:

```
"android.intent.category.DEFAULT"
```

Your error code says:

```
android.category.DEFAULT
```

Could that be it?

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm chiming in very late on this one, but I had the same error message.

In my case, the error was caused because I hadn't included the `<activity>...</activity>` code in *both* AndroidManifest.xml files. There is a /AndroidManifest.xml file and a /bin/AndroidManifest.xml file. I'm not sure if I'm doing something incorrect that results in the need for two identical files, but the only way I could get things to work is if the code was present in both of them.

Hopefully that helps somebody.